# How to get custom fonts to work on Google Colab so that I can use it to run manim(3b1b's animation software)

Tags: python, fonts, google-colaboratory, manim

I am trying to use Custom True Type fonts for rendering an animation using Manim on Google Colab. But for some reason, the animation is rendering without the custom font. I have tested code and it works perfectly on my local machine. It seems to be a problem of the fonts not being installed correctly. I have done exactly as other sources on the internet have suggested that is to move the `.ttf` files to the following directory: `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`

Can someone help me out with what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to follow these commands:

```
!wget "link_to_font_files_download"
!unzip "download?family=font_file_name"

!mv font_file.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/

!fc-cache -f -v
```